# Prove if $\mathbb{Z} \sqrt{p}$ has an element with norm q, then $\mathbb{Z} \sqrt{q}$ has no elements with norm p.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

p, q distinct primes and congruent to 3 mod 4.

Prove if $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{p}]$ has an element with norm q, then $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{q}]$ has no elements with norm p.

I know the norm of an element in $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{p}]$ is $x^2 - py^2$, but I'm not very sure how to proceed with the proof.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the OP meant an element $\in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}]$ of **ideal norm** $q$ ie. $$N(x+y\sqrt{p})=|x^2-y^2 p|=q$$

$x^2-py^2=q$ gives that $x^2+y^2=-1\bmod 4$ which is impossible.

So it must be $x^2-py^2=-q$.

Therefore, $-q$ is a square $\bmod p$ so that $q$ is **not** a square $\bmod p$ and $u^2-qv^2= \pm p$ has no solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate why $x^2-py^2 =q$ gives $x^2+y^2 = -1mod4$ please? @reuns